# Generic Method to find the median of 3 values

Tags: java, sorting, generics, median

I needed a method to get the median of 3 values, I thought it a good opportunity to write a generic method since I don't really have that practiced. I wrote this and it seems pretty straight-forward, though I get a warning, but it seems to work fine, according to my tests.

I'm aware I could use an inherently sorted set, or `Collections.sort()`, but this approach is for the sake of understanding.

I want to pinpoint a few things:

1. I noticed this doesn't work if I tried to declare `medianHelper` with `Arrays.asList(a, b, c)` why is this? Trying to search this gives me unrelated results and it's otherwise elusive since I'm not sure what is happening. I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`, but this is not present the way I have it below.
2. Why am I getting a warning? What is wrong/missing?

The method follows:

```
private static <T extends Comparable> T median(T a, T b, T c) {
    List<T> medianHelper = new ArrayList<>();
    T max;
    T min;

    medianHelper.add(a);
    medianHelper.add(b);
    medianHelper.add(c);

    if (a.compareTo(b) >= 0) {
        max = a;
        min = b;
    } else {
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }

    if (max.compareTo(c) == -1) {
        max = c;
    }

    if (min.compareTo(c) >= 0) {
        min = c;
    }

    medianHelper.remove(max);
    medianHelper.remove(min);

    return medianHelper.get(0);
}
```

Comment: What warning do you get ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't correctly introduced the type-parameter `T`, as `Comparable` is generic, too.

It should rather be:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T median(T a, T b, T c)
```

Furthermore, you can just **sort** the `medianHelper` list, since its elements **will** be `Comparable`. So your method can be significantly shortened to:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T median(T a, T b, T c) {
    List<T> medianHelper = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);

    Collections.sort(medianHelper);

    return medianHelper.get(1);
}
```

Note that `Arrays.asList()` returns an unmodifiable list, which means you're not allowed to add/remove elements after it's created. If you wish to do the comparisons yourself, you can use `new ArrayList<>` instead of `Arrays.asList()` and then manually add the elements to it.

Comment: That should even be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: Thank you, kocko. I completely overlooked that `Comparable` is generic, and thank you, fge for the important distinction that it also have an upper bound. I'm still perplexed on the topic of Arrays.asList errors if I want to do the comparisons myself. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns an unmodifiable list, which means you can add/remove objects from it. I guess that's the error you're receiving now. :) If you wish to do the comparisons yourself, you can use `new ArrayList<>` and then manually add the elements to it.

Comment: Thanks again, I think you should add that to your answer.